# Territory assignment rules based on global state/territory pick list

Tags: assignment-rules, territory-management, global-picklist

Looking for confirmation that territory assignment rules based on global state/territory picklist code value don't work against the ISO code and only the Name field of the picklist value. I am unable to get the rules to fire when creating the rule:

> ShippingStateProvinceCode = 'CA'

But I am able to get them to fire when using the "Name" field of the picklist:

> ShippingStateProvince = 'California'

Comment: Is it be cause it's a picklist? Could you try ISPICKVAL (ShippingStateProvinceCode, 'CA')?

Comment: Can you use formula within a filter value field?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Use Rules to Assign Accounts to Territories](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tm2_assign_accounts_by_rules.htm&siteLang=en_US) documentation,

> "If your org has enabled state and country picklists, territory
>   assignment rules using states as a criteria must use contains matching
>   instead of equals matching."